# Strange behavior in DescriptorMatcher.match()

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm getting error

`TypeError: DescriptorMatcher.match() takes at most 2 keyword arguments (3 given)`

using

```
bf = createMatcher(method, crossCheck=True)
bf.match(queryDescriptors=featuresA, trainDescriptors=featuresB, mask=masks)
```

The documentation for this function is here:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d39/classcv_1_1DescriptorMatcher.html#a3cc074710ccb466a662815969e14cf5e

It clearly states a third masks argument is accepted:

`matches  =   cv.DescriptorMatcher.match( queryDescriptors, trainDescriptors[, mask]  )`

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: I think those are positional parameters. Does `bf.match(featuresA, featuresB, masks)` work?

Comment: Same error. I've also tried 'mask' instead of 'masks'

Comment: Is there a way to force it to use the correct version of the overloaded function? The automatic argument detection thing is clearly not working correctly